# Angular form inputs not matching the data type as per the interface declared when being assigned

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-forms

Why is the form builder values not matching the type as per declared in the interface? How do I make sure that my numbers input do not get converted to string in the `formGroup`, given that I have strictly set that user can only input numbers.

I have a sample form here:

```
<form [formGroup]="exampleForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Name: </label>
      <input class="form-control" formControlName="name">

    <br><label>Age: </label>
      <input class="form-control" formControlName="age">

    <br><button>Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

and an interface that has the exact same attributes as the form inputs:

```
export interface SampleInterface {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}
```

upon submission of the form, I assign the form values to the interface object instance. I thought that this would then automatically match the `age` to `number` type as per the interface. However, this is not the case as I tried to print the interface object instance and I am seeing it being taken as a string.

In my `component.ts`:

```
  onSubmit(){
    let submittedData = this.exampleForm.value;
    this.sampleObject = submittedData;
    console.log(this.sampleObject);
  }
```

This is being printed in the console:

```
>{name: "Mike", age: "20"}
age: "20"
name: "Mike"
__proto__: Object
```

You may find the demo [HERE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-n5syvv).

Comment: Interfaces are more for structuring, helping linting, and improved code practices. They don't deal with type conversion. If you inspect your website's sources, you'll notice there are no interfaces, apart from references in the maps. Your input `age` is an input that accepts a string and is pushing that into the javascript object accordingly. Add the `type="number"` attribute to your age input, If I remember correctly that should work.

Comment: In my actual source code I have set it such a way that the user can only input numbers. I do not understand why it is being converted to string in the ```this.formGroup.value```. Yes, setting ```type="number"``` works however I do not want to have the up and down arrow in my input field so I didn't use them

Comment: It's not being converted to a string. It is already a string, You will need to deal with converting the string to a number if you don't want to use the `type` attribute. You can do that with `int.Parse(ageString)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I put in my comment, interfaces do not deal with type conversion, and the input field is using strings as it's default behaviour.

Add the `type` attribute to your age and set to number.

```html
<form [formGroup]="exampleForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Name: </label>
      <input class="form-control" formControlName="name">

    <br><label>Age: </label>
      <input class="form-control" type="number" formControlName="age">

    <br><button>Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Updated stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jjrkaj

-Update-

To remove the up and down from number inputs, in your global styles you can apply the following style.

`styles.css`

```css
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button { 
  -webkit-appearance: none; 
  margin: 0; 
}
```

Or you could create a directive, to sit on the number, which handles parsing, but that might be overkill.

Comment: Yes, it works however I do not want to have the up and down arrow in the input field that's why I did not use it.

Comment: it works! thank you for explaining and the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML `<input>` field handles inputs as strings by default. TypeScript's type handling is only a compilation aid on top of JavaScript, and doesn't actually change the any-type nature of the underlying JavaScript variables.

Correction: `type="number"` will help, which I didn't think was true before.

Comment: Yeah, I couldn't quite remember if `type="number"` deals with the setting the value as the specific type, but remembered that `type="date"` will give you a type of date.